# Finding the /dev/input/event* path of a device from its name

Tags: shell-script, udev, input

I need to find a gamepad in my list of /dev/input/event* devices, and the only thing I know about it is that when I do `evtest` it shows up with the name `G13`.
The problem is every time I reboot it gets a different number. I would like to automate finding the path so I can pass it to this command in the `$G13` variable:
I tried `evtest | grep G13` but the problem is the evtest command doesn't terminate on its own, it's interactive, so my script gets stuck on a prompt.

```
xboxdrv --evdev $G13 --config ~/.config/xboxdrv/G13.conf &
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to set up a [udev](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/udev) rule to provide your device with a persistent symlink. Start by running `udevadm info -a /dev/input/eventXX` for whichever device currently represents your gamepad.

You'll see output like:

```
    ATTR{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/input/input29':
    KERNELS=="input29"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="input"
    DRIVERS==""
    ...
    ATTRS{id/product}=="c21d"
    ATTRS{id/vendor}=="046d"
    ...
```

Create a file `/etc/udev/rules.d/90-gamepad.rules` that contains:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="input", ATTRS{id/product}=="c21d", ATTRS{id/vendor}=="046d", SYMLINK += "gamepad"
```

...replacing the values for product and vendor with the ones you see
in your output.

Save the file and run:

```
udevadm control -R
```

Unplug the gamepad and plug it back in, and you should see there is
now a symlink `/dev/gamepad` that points to the appropriate
`/dev/input/...` device.

Now you can use the device path `/dev/gamepad` instead of the varying
`/dev/input` path.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: One year later correction: this creates a symlink to the /dev/input/jsY path, not to the /dev/input/eventXX path. Unfortunately, the command in the question cannot work with that path. I can only assume they are different protocols or something

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, sharing my solution for others:

On Ubuntu 22.04, [install the xboxdrv](https://askubuntu.com/questions/695069/xbox-controller-blinking/1438948#1438948)

Check the udev attributes of in my case *event5* (iterate over all events to find the right one):

```
$ udevadm info -a /dev/input/event5

looking at device '/devices/virtual/input/input5/event5':
KERNEL=="event5"
SUBSYSTEM=="input"
DRIVER==""
ATTR{power/control}=="auto"
ATTR{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
ATTR{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
ATTR{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"

looking at parent device '/devices/virtual/input/input5':
KERNELS=="input5"
SUBSYSTEMS=="input"
DRIVERS==""
ATTRS{capabilities/abs}=="3061b"
ATTRS{capabilities/ev}=="b"
ATTRS{capabilities/ff}=="0"
ATTRS{capabilities/key}=="7cdb000000000000 0 0 0 0"
ATTRS{capabilities/led}=="0"
ATTRS{capabilities/msc}=="0"
ATTRS{capabilities/rel}=="0"
ATTRS{capabilities/snd}=="0"
ATTRS{capabilities/sw}=="0"
ATTRS{id/bustype}=="0000"
ATTRS{id/product}=="0000"
ATTRS{id/vendor}=="0000"
ATTRS{id/version}=="0000"
ATTRS{inhibited}=="0"
ATTRS{name}=="Xbox Gamepad (userspace driver)"
ATTRS{phys}==""
ATTRS{power/control}=="auto"
ATTRS{power/runtime_active_time}=="0"
ATTRS{power/runtime_status}=="unsupported"
ATTRS{power/runtime_suspended_time}=="0"
ATTRS{properties}=="0"
ATTRS{uniq}==""
```

Put the following in /etc/udev/rules.d, using the name to filter:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="input" ATTRS{name}=="Xbox Gamepad (userspace driver)" MODE="0666" SYMLINK+="/input/xbox-controller"
```

Reload the udev rules

```
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules && sudo udevadm trigger
```

Check that the symlink indeed points to event5 and not to js0:

```
$ ll /dev/input/xbox-controller 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 6 dec 29 15:11 /dev/input/xbox-controller -> event5
```

In my case I need to use the device in a docker, and using the direct symlink won´t work. So I resolve the symlink [using "readlink"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54831029) before I use it:

```
docker run --device=$(readlink -f /dev/input/xbox-controller)
```

So in your case you could probably replace the $G13 variable with

```
$(readlink -f /dev/input/xbox-controller)
```